# python - 'NoneType' object error when I want the object to have a None value?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that searches a directory's `.txt` files and flags any files whose contents match a user's input through regex.

```
os.chdir(folder)
variableRegex = re.compile(variable)
for file in os.listdir(folder):
    if file.endswith('.txt'):
        filename = file
        open(file)
        open(file).read()
        file = variableRegex.search(open(file).read())
        if file.group() is None:
            print(filename + " negative.")
        else:
            print(filename + " positive.")
```

The program functions when `file.group()` is *not* equal to `None`, i.e. when there's a match. However, the program returns an error whenever file.group() is equal to None, even though that's a normal function I want to happen in this program.

```
Set what variable to analyze for.
al
Set what folder to analyze.
C:\regextest
regex1.txt positive.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<myembarrassingusername>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\automatepython\regexsearch.py", line 20, in <module>
    if file.group() is None:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

The directory `C:\regextest` has two `.txt` files, the first having 'al' and the other having a different name inside of it. How do I get this program to accept the `None` value without receiving an error?

P.S. If you're curious, the variable and folder variables were inputted in before by input().

Comment: If file is the one that need checking, why you use `file.group()` ?! The error is caused because file is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added code to check whether the variable `file` is of type `None`

```
os.chdir(folder)
variableRegex = re.compile(variable)
for file in os.listdir(folder):
    if file.endswith('.txt'):
        filename = file
        open(file)
        open(file).read()
        file = variableRegex.search(open(file).read())
        
        #Added Code Here
        NoneType=type(None)
        if(type(file)!=NoneType):
            if file.group() is None:
               print(filename + " negative.")
            else:
               print(filename + " positive.")
        else:
            print("Your Logic Here to Handle Such Cases")
```